# My webview app doesn't open

Tags: android, eclipse

I have made an webview app. but it doesn't work.
He is stuck when i test it on an android device

FullscreenActivity.java

```
package com.solidos.neshaniha;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class FullscreenActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

        webView.loadUrl("http://www.mywebsite.nl/");



    }


}
```

activity_fullscreen.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#0099cc"
 tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

 </FrameLayout>
```

Who can help me?

Thanx

Comment: initialize the web view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a webview in there at all. Change your layout to:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#0099cc"
    tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your Activity do:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.loadUrl("http://m.neshaniha.org/");
}
```

Also make sure this is in your `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't initialize the webview.

Like this :

```
private WebView webView;

webview = (Webview)findViewById(R.id.webview1);
WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webview.loadURL("nananan");
```

Answer (score 0):

Add webView in xml as below:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#0099cc"
tools:context=".FullscreenActivity" >

<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Please initialize the WebView as below:

```
WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
webView.loadUrl("http://m.neshaniha.org/");
```

Answer (score 0):

First go like that:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
```

You should define the `@+id` of your `WebView`, like that:

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your java code, you declared your WebView as a member variable, but you are not initialising it to anything.  Therefore when you try to open the URL in it, you are getting a `NullPointerException`.  There are two issues with your code.

First, you need to add the WebView to your layout:

```
<FrameLayout ...>
    <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" ... />
</FrameLayout>
```

Then in your java code you need to find this webview and assign it to your variable before loading the url:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_fullscreen);

    webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.loadUrl("http://m.neshaniha.org/");
}
```